# Alternate definition of symmetric group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, permutation-cycles

Let $S_3$ act on $\Re^3$ by the permutation matrices P(σ), where P(σ)
permutes the basis vectors: $$P(σ)(e_i) = e_{σ(i)}$$

Show that, with this
formula,
$$\sigma(x_1,x_2,x_3) = P(\sigma)(x_1e_1 + x_2e_2  + x_3e_3) = (x_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}, x_{\sigma^{-1}(2)}, x_{\sigma^{-1}(3)} )$$

this is an action of $S_3$ on $\Re^3$.

It seems to me that this is not true, since the inverse of a product flips the order. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Flipping the order is not an issue unless you are insisting that the action be on a specific side. Given any left action of a finite group, you can turn it into a right action by declaring that $x\cdot g = g^{-1}\cdot x$, and vice versa.

Given your specific example, composition of functions permuting indices is a bit weird in terms of the side the action is on. In general, if you define
$$\sigma \cdot (x_a,x_b,x_c) = (x_{\sigma(a)},x_{\sigma(b)},x_{\sigma(c)})$$
then it actually follows that
$$\sigma\cdot \tau \cdot (x_a,x_b,x_c) = (x_{\tau\sigma(a)},x_{\tau\sigma(b)},x_{\tau\sigma(c)})$$
This is a valid action, but it is not on the left side. It is a right action.

Comment: Hm, I think in my case then I am trying to show that this new definition gives us a left action such that: $$\sigma\cdot\tau\cdot(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (x_{\sigma^{-1}\tau^{-1}(a)}, .. , ..)$$

Comment: @51n84d It's actually more of a causal thing. The linear transformation acts on the left. Therefore you get the inverse permutation when you apply it.

Comment: @51n84d But yes, that is what you are trying to show.

Comment: Is it not the case that $(\sigma\cdot\tau)^{-1} = \tau^{-1}\sigma^{-1}$? Doesn't the inverse flip the order here?

Comment: @51n84d The inverse flips order of multiplication, but applying the permutation of the indices also flips the order. So it flips it back.

Comment: Sorry for the incessant questions, but why exactly does permuting the indices flip the order?

Comment: @51n84d Work out an example with permutations that don't commute and you'll see.